# C# Format String with double quotes around directories with spaces

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to use a String.Format to create the following string

2MSFX.exe "C:\Users\Avidan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DefferedRenderer\DummyGame\DummyGameContent\Shaders\Clear.fx" "C:\Users\Avidan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DefferedRenderer\DummyGame\DummyGameContent\Shaders\Clear.mxfb"

so i am trying to use String.Format, but i just can't seen to get my head around it for some reason :|

The code is (where last 2 params are String.Empty):

```
 String outputFile = Path.Combine(destDir, Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetFileName(fxFile), "mgxf"));
 String command = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"{3}\"",  Path.GetFullPath(fxFile),  Path.GetFullPath(outputFile), DX11Support, DebugSupport);

                var proc = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = MGFXApp,
                        Arguments = command,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    }
                };
```

But that appears to be giving me
\"C:\Users\Avidan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DefferedRenderer\DummyGame\DummyGameContent\Shaders\ClearGBuffer.fx\" \"C:\Users\Avidan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DefferedRenderer\DummyGame\DummyGameContent\Shaders\MGFX\ClearGBuffer.mgxf\" \"\" \"\"

If i use the verbatim string i can't get it to create the string i want.

Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: is there any specific reason you want it to convert? I believe you need to put "@" before the string to avoid the errors .

Comment: If i use String.Format(@"\"{0}\"....); It thinks i am saying i want the string \ and i'm following it then with some invalid syntax of {0}\ then a new string at the next "

Comment: Tested with dummy values but your format string works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

You should use `String.Concat()`.

```
String.Concat("\"", Path.GetFullPath(fxFile), "\" " , Path.GetFullPath(outputFile), "\" " DX11Support,"\" " ,DebugSupport, "\"")
```

Comment: Sorry it may nto be clear above but it is two String i need the output to be "PathOne" "PathTwo" where as this seems to give me PathOne\\PathTwo

Comment: Excellent, thanks ended up using
String command = String.Concat("\"", Path.GetFullPath(fxFile), "\" " , "\"",Path.GetFullPath(outputFile), "\" " + DX11Support + " " + DebugSupport);

Answer (score 2):

For a simple case like this, I wouldn't think it necessary, but you could create an extension method to automatically put quotes around the strings.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Quotify(this string s)
    {
        return string.Format("\"{0}\"", s);
    }
}
```

Then your command format looks like this:

```
String command = String.Join(" ",
    Path.GetFullPath(fxFile).Quotify(),
    Path.GetFullPath(outputFile).Quotify(),
    DX11Support.Quotify(), DebugSupport.Quotify());
```

Comment: Well, but this means that the original string should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of the @ literal to avoid '\' squirlyness, and ""'s to make "'s

This example works for me:

```
string s = @"""C:\Test Dir\file.fx"" ""C:\Test Dir\SubDir\input.dat""";
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Console output looks like this:

```
"C:\Test Dir\file.fx" "C:\Test Dir\SubDir\input.dat"
```

Just remember that two quotes makes a single quote, so the triple quote at the beginning and end of the string are the quote to start the string definition, and then a double quote to make a quote.  Possibly one of the more confusing string formats out there, but that's how it works.

Comment: Thanks, but the files are a dynamic list of files so i can't have the list hard coded.
That's why i am trying to get the String.Format working, so i can build the command line args easier.